# Migrate bluemix app to another organization (another person's account)

Tags: ibm-cloud

Is it possible to migrate a bluemix app from one person's account to another person's account?
One of my teammates is leaving the team. We will need to migrate the app from his account to an existing member's one.

Comment: Is this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239288/ibm-bluemix-application-migration-between-accounts/45277140#45277140

Answer (score 1):

You can rebuild and redeploy the application to a different space, just change the target space and organization that you want to target.  Also make sure that you have the needed services deployed in that new org/space.