# How to move a Bluemix DevOps project to another account

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have an IBM DevOps Bluemix project in one of my Bluemix accounts and I need to move it to one of my other Bluemix Accounts. How do I do that in the new Bluemix DevOps?

Comment: Gave an answer to this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452249/migrate-bluemix-app-to-another-organization-another-persons-account, and a related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239288/ibm-bluemix-application-migration-between-accounts/45277140#45277140.

Answer (score 0):

you could take a look at the cloud foundry cli plugins. here is one - https://github.com/mevansam/cf-copy-plugin. This allows you to copy from one space/org/target to another